# Create ascending ID in group by

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have this table

```
+-----------+-------------+
| FoodType  |    Food     |
+-----------+-------------+
| Fruits    | Apple       |
| Fruits    | Orange      |
| Meat      | Beef        |
| Meat      | Chicken     |
| Meat      | Pork        |
| Vegetable | Cauliflower |
| Vegetable | Leek        |
+-----------+-------------+
```

How do I want create a new column (`GroupID`) that generates an unique ID for data grouped by FoodType in a specfic order (for example, ordered by `FoodType` and `Food`:

```
+-----------+-------------+---------+
| FoodType  |    Food     | GroupID |
+-----------+-------------+---------+
| Fruits    | Apple       |       1 |
| Fruits    | Orange      |       2 |
| Meat      | Beef        |       1 |
| Meat      | Chicken     |       2 |
| Meat      | Pork        |       3 |
| Vegetable | Cauliflower |       1 |
| Vegetable | Leek        |       2 |
+-----------+-------------+---------+
```

I have this simple query:

```
SELECT  FoodType, Food
FROM    Food
GROUP BY FoodType, Food
```

but I do not know how to generate the ID...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ROW_NUMBER()` with the appropriate `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses:

```
SELECT FoodType, Food, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FoodType ORDER BY Food)
FROM Food
```

Comment: Thank you, I was stucked with the idea of using a CTE

Comment: @RegularNormalDayGuy A CTE becomes useful if you then want to filter on only the smallest or biggest, or the first three, or delete all but the smallest, etc.